Why are there so many 'broken' plurals in Arabic?
Textbooks to learn Arabic usually mention between 14 and 17 rules to form the plurals of nouns, this number depending on whether or not particular plurals are considered by the author to be ‘broken’ (for instance some fruits and vegetables end in ة and the plural simply drops it, so sometimes it is not counted as broken, etc.).

What is known about the origin of such multiplicity?

It is certainly not present in modern Hebrew, where there are only two gender-dependent plural forms with only a handful of exceptions, and I don't think biblical Hebrew to be much more involved, although probably having more exceptions.
On the other hand, Indo-European languages like German also display numerous rules (up to 8, I believe) but those are quite intuitive and ultimately depend mostly on word length and gender.
I wonder why in the standardization process conducted during the XIX c. scholars did not unify and reduce the number of the different forms, which in my opinion is the most challenging aspect of the Arabic morphology to master for learners.

I'm not going to attempt an answer (I don't know enough about the development of Semitic languages - though I do know that "broken plurals" are not unique to Arabic). But what I want to say is that grenerally when people try to codify and standardise languages, the needs of learners are of very low significance. Children learn the languages they are exposed to without significant effort: why should the reformers care about the (usually) relatively small number of adult learners?

I think you're a bit optimistic about the complexity of German plurals, I find them rather unpredictable as a native speaker

In addition to what Colin Fine said, if you want to standardize something, there usually have to be competing forms to begin with, of which you can brand one as “standard”. It is much harder to convince users to start using new forms. So your question presupposes a variation that I’m not sure was present at the time.

@ColinFine Not necessarily "adult [foreign] learners" but learners of all kinds. In the case of Arabic it is significant because it was thought to be standardized among other things to allow for a mutual understanding of the diverse Arabic  speaking peoples, and essentially SA is a different language compared to most dialects; so definitely learning the "eloquent Arabic" (as it is called) is an effort for the macro-Arabic speakers- and even more so, during the XIX, early XX c. where access to education was very scarce in the region.

@ColinFine Following your comment. There are also examples where the needs of the learners where important to reformers. Modern Hebrew for instance was 'reformed' taking away a huge amount of technicalities in every aspect (grammar, pronunciation, etc) with the scope of making it more accessible to learners. Also, the Bolshevik  orthography and spelling reform had among its motivations making the instruction less cumbersome in schools.

@Keelan That was not the case in Arabic. Standard Arabic is not based on a prestigious dialect or spoken variant like the Florentine dialect that became Italian, etc. SA is based on the Qur'an and high early medieval poetry, a form of the language that even then people did not speak ("SA has never been spoken" says Munther Younes, a recognized arabologist ). Bottom line, my question does not "presuppose a variation"

@JohnFrazer I agree it's involved. But sometimes native speakers tend to exaggerate the 'difficulty' (however you can define it) of their own languages. If you look at books to learn German for foreigners -not the ones by Langenscheidt or German publishers- it is not that terrible as  natives may think, or at least in my humble opinion it is not a tenth of difficult as Arabic in regards to plurals.

the words you mention that end in ta marbuta only in the singular are definitely not broken plurals (although they aren't sound plurals either), they're singulatives formed from a collective noun. Note that the singulative can often itself be pluralised. Confusingly the same suffix can also be used to form collective nouns from normal countable nouns

the only broken plural pattern reconstructible for Proto-Semitic is the segholate pattern *CVCC- > *CVCaC- (although note that in many branches this has ended up double marked with the regular sound plural), but it's likely Proto-Semitic originally had more (seeing as a wide variety of "broken plural"-like patterns are attested in other Afroasiatic languages and Arabic, Sayhadic, Modern South Arabian, and Afrosemitic attest (relics of) other patterns

unfortunately I don't think the details are well understood

I did find a couple of books that may be useful, but I haven't read them so can't summarise and turn them into an answer. The first is Murtonen, 1964, Broken plurals; origin and development of the system, from Brill. The second is Ratcliffe, 1998, The “Broken” Plural Problem in Arabic and Comparative Semitic: Allomorphy and analogy in non-concatenative morphology, from John Benjamins Publishing Company

also note that Suchard & Groen's 2021 paper argues that the segholate pattern is not a broken plural, but a result of regular epenthesis in an illegal CCC cluster (they argue a suffix beginning in *w underlies the sound plural) and that Proto-Semitic had this "double marking" making it distinct from the "genuine" broken plurals

Your comment kind of supports my point. In the case of Italian you mention, there were competing dialects from which one form could be chosen, so there is a choice and one can choose to simplify the system. In the case of Standard Arabic as you describe it, it is a formalization of the language found in a collection of texts that is not even written in a single variety. If such formalization is the goal (rather than simplification), a complex system is the logical result.

The posted inquiry has two questions:

What is the origin of the numerous Arabic broken plural patterns that would account for so many different patterns?

Why were these patterns not simplified during the Arabic "standardization" movement of the 19th Century?


I will try to address these in reverse order.

Why were these patterns not simplified during the Arabic "standardization" movement of the 19th Century?

The 19-20th Century language movement in Arabic was not a movement toward standardization, but rather “modernization.”  It was part of a cultural “awakening” or “renaissance” (النّهضة) and therefore fundamentally different in character from what happened to languages like Modern German, Mandarin, or Norwegian Nynorsk, where individuals had to make explicit choices in language design between a variety of different dialect possibilities.
The Arabic movement was also fundamentally different from the revitalization of Modern Hebrew, which had a primary challenge of creating a spoken medium for the language, encouraging use of the language for daily activities, and teaching the language to entire communities of non-Hebrew speakers.
The challenge for Arabic was to expand the use of formal Arabic to areas of cultural and technical life that were associated with the use of Turkish, English, or French and had no precedents in Arabic.  They were under pressure to adopt and modernize vocabulary and to create new literary forms, like newspapers and novels.  There was little need to address syntax or morphology directly since the language had always been in continuous use.
As far as I am aware, there is little difference at the systemic level between the basic formation of noun plurals among Classical Arabic, Modern Standard Arabic, and modern dialects like Egyptian Arabic.  The Wikipedia article on Egyptian Arabic lists 23-24 different plural patterns, which is certainly no simpler than the 14-17 patterns of Modern Standard Arabic referenced in the initial question.  Getting rid of broken plurals from formal Arabic would have been a radical departure from most varieties of spoken Arabic.

What is the origin of the numerous Arabic broken plural patterns that would account for so many different patterns?

Languages vary widely in how they deal with grammatical number, and the patterns found in English and German (primarily a mandatory contrast between singular and plural) is by no means universal.  Some languages do not really have grammatical number at all (e.g., Pirah̀ã, Japanese, and Mandarin), and some mark contrasts of various levels of plurality like Arabic.
A full analysis of number in Arabic must address singular vs. dual vs. plural, singulatives vs. collectives, animate vs. inanimate, simple plurals vs. plurals of plurals, and possible paucal plurals vs. greater plurals (See .  Such potential complexity of categories gives scope to complexity in form.
Plurality in Arabic nouns is primarily indicated through its templatic system (i.e., through broken plurals) and only secondarily through plural suffixes.  Broken plurals are the result of apophony, which seems to have been a widespread feature of ancient and modern Afroasiatic languages that resulted in broken plurals to varying extents.   Broken plurals exist or have existed in other branches of Afroasiatic languages, such as Berber languages and Coptic. There is even evidence of them in Hebrew.  (See Robert Ratcliff says in Journal of Near Eastern Studies, Vol. 57, No. 2 (Apr., 1998), pp. 98 and 99).
Although Arabic shares broken plurals with many branches of Afroasiatic languages, it may be that the particular patterns are shared only with South Semitic languages.  For instance, Ge’ez, an ancient South Semitic language of the horn of Africa, had extensive broken plurals, many of which seem to have patterns similar to Arabic.  (See Massimo Villa’s “Observations on some 'broken' plurals of Gə'əz”)
Some scholars have noted that the form of singulars and plurals of Arabic are much less random than they seem.  For instance, Robert Ratcliff says in Journal of Near Eastern Studies, Vol. 57, No. 2 (Apr., 1998), pp. 81-123 (43 pages):

The fact that the traditional grammars offer very little analysis of
relationships between forms or patterns has led to a mistaken
assumption that such relationships cannot be categorized or do not
exist. Thus, with regard to the issue at hand, a traditional
assumption has been that the association of singulars to broken
plurals is largely random or unpredictable and that there is no formal
relationship between singulars and plurals. The first assumption is
mistaken, as statistical studies such as those of A. Murtonen and M.
Levy have shown,"11 while the second assumption largely depends on the
theoretic or analytical framework adopted. Recent theoretical work
under the rubric of autosegmental or prosodic morphology has greatly
enriched the formal apparatus available for analysis of morphological
systems like those found in Arabic and has consequently opened the way
for a clearer understanding of the formal basis of the relationship
between singulars and plurals.

Others say that they forms of singular and plural can be related through various polarity contrasts that can sometimes go in either direction: high vowels vs. low vowels (ḥimār vs. ḥamīr), short vowels vs. long vowels (jund vs. junūd and kitāb vs. kutub), trochaic for singular vs. iambic for plural (qidḥ vs. qidāḥ), prefixed/metathesis vs. prefix-less (rijl vs. arjul), suffixed vs suffix-less (ra’īs vs. ru’asā’), and combinations of these (’azraq vs. zurq vs. zurqā’ and rajul vs. rijāl). (See, e.g., William Worrell’s “The Formation of Arabic Broken Plurals”)
If you take all these polarities into account, you can even develop an algorithm to construct plurals that has some predictive value.  (See Learn Arabic Online)  The many exceptions and unpredictable patterns can to some extent be explained through ancient and surface phonetic issues (e.g., missing vowels or the presence of certain types of consonants), analogy based on perceived categorical similarity, the semantic coloring that some templates have, and the need to differentiate some meanings from others (e.g, rijāl (men) vs. arjul (feet)).
